# Pair Programming Screen Share/Control Tool for Mac

Tags: osx, programming, screen-sharing

I'm looking for a tool which would allow users to pair program on a Mac platform.  Our developers use Xcode, but the main criteria for this program would be to allow two developers to connect over the internet, allow one to share their screen, but both developers could use their keyboard and mouse to control the currently shared screen.

We have previously used [Screenhero](https://screenhero.com/) for this purpose, but due to their recent acquisition by Slack, they are end-of-lifing their standalone product and requiring a paid Slack account.  This tool would also be used for interviews, and we want to refrain from adding users to our Slack account just to interview with us.

Are there any similar tools like Screenhero which could be used to pair and allow control of another developer's computer over a network?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at http://www.use-together.com/screenhero-alternative/ which is a perfect solution for remote pair programming.

Answer (score 1):

Now there is also [Tuple](https://tuple.app). Warning though: they will charge you for accounts that were not even setup by the person who was invited. Pretty clueless. The tool works pretty well but it's C++ and for now, Mac only.